# How to pass the time on a six-hour layover with small children (in Frankfurt)?

Tags: layovers, children

We're having a six-hour layover at Frankfurt Airport in August, waiting for a flight to the USA. We arrive at ~8:00 and depart at ~14:00. My children are 4.5 and 8 years old.

I'm looking for the best ideas to pass the time Is there anything to do at the airport (I saw there are some small playgrounds but nothing where I would wait six hours)? Can we go out for a stroll? I guess we would have to be back at the airport three hours before the flight.

Answer (score 5):

Frankfurt airport is well connected to the city of Frankfurt by trains, which take only 11 minutes and run every 15 min or so.  So you can easily go explore the city and come back in time for your flight, particularly if one or more of your flights is a "Euro-domestic" Schengen flight with no immigration to pass through (since this is the one place in Frankfurt that occasionally gets jammed).

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I don't particularly want to get into the city (been there before). Do you think taking a taxi to some of the nearby lakes is worth it?  Something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOE12.png

Answer (score 3):

This started out as a comment to the image the OP referred to in another answer.

[image]

Looking on Google the end of your proposed taxi ride is apparently called `Strandbad Langener Waldsee`.  If you google this name you will find lots of good reviews on places like Trip Advisor saying that it is a nice, clean place to spend some time swimming.  Summarizing what I saw from various reviews:

- Good, clean family friendly location
- Had an entrance fee €3 per person per day in 2015
- There is a bar/snackbar
- Clothing optional was mentioned in some older reviews
- The cement works on the lake shore detract from the view
- There doesn't seem to be much shade
- One person said if you get there in the morning you will have the place to yourself

I was not able to determine if you are able to rent towels or beach umbrellas.

What I would caution is spending 1/2 day in the sun at the beach before a long flight.  `Sunburnt children on a plane` sounds like the plot of a horror story!

On the other hand, sleeping under a tree/umbrella before your flight sounds like a great way to relax.

Comment: Thanks, tripadvisor is a good resource. As of 2014 there were no umbrellas/towels to rent (https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g227879-d2431313-r211547514-Langener_Waldsee-Langen_Hesse.html).  I'm also considering "Badesee Waldorf".